# iOS Error Parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsstring

I am new to iOS. I have this JSON data that I needed to parse:

```
{  
   "allseries":[  
      {  
         "type":"HR",
         "title":"Heart Rate",
         "xLabel":"Time",
         "yLabel":"Beats per Min",
         "defaultUnit":"BPM",
         "url":"info/info?user=admin%40korrent.com&type=HR",
         "size":18,
         "firstTs":1406755651,
         "lastTs":1406841254
      },
      {  
         "type":"TEMP",
         "title":"Temperature",
         "xLabel":"Time",
         "yLabel":"Temperature",
         "defaultUnit":"F",
         "url":"info/info?user=admin%40korrent.com&type=TEMP",
         "size":6,
         "firstTs":1406854147,
         "lastTs":1406854283
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

So far this is my code:

```
NSString *dataReceived= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"--> async response data (string): %@", dataReceived);
NSData *jsonData = [dataReceived dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"JSON key and value %@", [dict description]);
NSLog(@" %@ ", dict[@"allseries"]);
NSString *jsonString=dict[@"allseries"];
   if (_programState == 4){
    NSLog(@"state is 4");
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
    NSData *Data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, the code throws invalid argument exception for this line:

```
 NSData *Data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Further more, jsonString seems totally "inoperable". I cannot split it, append strings to it etc. So what's wrong?

Comment: You have `_responseData`, just use it in `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData` you are adding code that is not only needed but incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// The following two lines are just for logging and otherwise are not needed.
NSString *dataReceived= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"--> async response data (string): %@", dataReceived);

// Deserialize the JSON data into a dictionary
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: _responseData options:nil error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"JSON key and value %@", dict);

// Get the array from the dictionary element "allseries".
NSArray *jsonArray = dict[@"allseries"];
NSLog(@"jsonArray: %@", jsonArray);
```

Here `jsonArray` is the array of dictionaries for "allseries" from the JSON

Comment: Hmmm, but why did iOS let you set NSString to NSArray in run time? Only when you tried to do operations did that iOS throw an exception. That makes no sense.

Comment: When you downcast a type the compiler says: "OK, I hope you know what you are doing, there are consequences at run-time if you are wrong". Then when you call a method that does not exist the run-time says: "Woha, that is not a method on the class instance, I'm going to crash -- or whatever!". If it is Canadian it will also say: "Sorry", Canadians are so polite, Eh?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though I don't think I quite understood what you said about Canadians

Answer (score 0):

What you did is totally, totally wrong.

dict[@allseries] is not an NSString. It is an NSArray with two elements, and both its elements are NSDictionary.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue in the question. Though this will be a problem when the original issue is fixed.

Comment: Maddy, look at the code again. He's extracting an NSArray and treats it as an NSString. What you are talking about is inefficient, but not an issue that stops it from working.

Comment: I didn't say that your answer wan't an issue. I'm saying that the OP's immediate issue is preventing the code from getting to the issue you pointed out. What you point out doesn't cause the error in the question.